# Trouble installing "ordinal" package

Tags: error-handling, install.packages, ordinal

I cannot get the "ordinal" package to install, though all other packages will install just fine. I am using the latest version of R (no updates available, according to the "Check for Updates" button in the Help menu). Is anyone else having trouble installing that particular package? Do you have suggestions for how to fix this? Here is the error output:

```
typ> install.packages("ordinal")
also installing the dependency ‘ucminf’

Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.1/PACKAGES'
Packages which are only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘ucminf’ ‘ordinal’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘ucminf’, ‘ordinal’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ucminf_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 16533 bytes (16 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 16 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ordinal_2022.11-16.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 805654 bytes (786 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 786 KB

* installing *source* package ‘ucminf’ ...
** package ‘ucminf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran -mtune=native -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c fortran.f -o fortran.o
make: /opt/R/arm64/bin/gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [fortran.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ucminf’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/ucminf’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ucminf’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ucminf’ is not available for package ‘ordinal’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/ordinal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ordinal’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/s7/z0jt94k5047g11wz1nbb3fnr0000gn/T/RtmpyoGcHs/downloaded_packages’e here
```

I used the install.packages("ordinal") command but the package did not install.

Comment: Try reinstalling R on your device. I faced the same, reinstalling R fixed the issue.  Apparently, R is looking for Fortran in a different directory than it originally is. Reinstalling R fixes this issue and sets the correct path.

Comment: Yes, I came up with a similar realization. I was using the most updated version of RSTudio but needed to update base R. Thanks for the response!